# emails comes from third party into salesforce if contact email and sender email same create task

Tags: tasks, apex-email-service

I have created email service and its activate and anyone can send email. When i'm sending email from gmail into salesforce it showing error in debug log that

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type:
>   0039E000002PRSZQA4: [OwnerId]

how to create task when email match to existing email of contact

```
global class ContactFrmEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

        String con_Email = envelope.fromAddress;

        System.debug('--@@--con_Email--'+con_Email);

        List<Contact> con = [SELECT Id, Email FROM contact WHERE email =: con_EMail LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('--@@--con--'+con);       

        if(con[0].email == con_Email) {
            Task T = new Task();
            T.Type = 'Email';
            T.OwnerId = con[0].id; //user id
            //T.WhatId = ; //record id
            insert T;
        }

        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T.OwnerId` field must be a User Id. In your code, you are assigning a Contact Id.

See here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

> **OwnerId**: ID of the **User who owns the record**. Label is
>   Assigned To ID.
>
> **WhoId**: The WhoId represents a human such as a lead or a
>   contact. WhoIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhoId is
>   equivalent to a **contact’s ID** or a lead’s ID. The label is Name ID.
>
> **WhatId:** The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as **accounts,
>   opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects**. WhatIds are
>   polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a
>   related object. The label is Related To ID.

So your code could be something like this:

```
Task T = new Task();
T.Type = 'Email';
T.OwnerId = assignedUser.Id; // user id
T.WhoId = con[0].id; // contact id
//T.WhatId = relatedTo.Id; // related record id
insert T;
```